# Writing OutputStream or byte array to browser

Tags: java, html, browser, java-io

I am trying to write `OutputStream` or byte array directly to browser  without using servlet.

Is there any Java  API to do that?

Comment: What does the stream or array contain?  I know of a way to push small images directly to a browser.  What is producing the data (applet, goblins,..)?

Comment: Wow! You are a Java superman!

Comment: It will be just string output lets assume a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ServerSocket` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) to listen on port 80.

If a request comes in, `accept()` it and use the resulting `Socket`'s `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` methods to grab stream objects to handle the data transfer with.

Then just parse out the request coming in on the `InputStream` and send your reply (**including HTTP headers!!!**) through the `OutputStream`. Then, close the connection and you're done.

If you need to write a server that can actually handle many simultaneous requests without taking a performance hit, you should definitely check out Java's NIO framework. Do **not** use one Thread per connection, if scalable performance is an issue.